# Why can my function not use same keywords on DB2 LUW?

Tags: sql, db2-luw

I have following function on IBM i DB2 and want to use it on DB2 LUW (Linux). The error I receive is "Multiple or conflicting keywords involving the "FENCED" clause are present.. SQLCODE=-628, SQLSTATE=42613".
Why can I not use it? The documentation lists the keywords, so I do not understand...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getHex2Char(IN_HEXCHAR VARCHAR(8))
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
NO EXTERNAL ACTION 
BEGIN
-- Do some SQL stuff and return result
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currently supported Db2-LUW versions allow the clause `called on null input`  ( the syntax `null call` has the same meaning ) with the `create function` statement.

But the function can return a NULL or a NOT NULL value , when the input is null.

The Db2 for i implementation of `returns null on null input` is not currently in the Db2-LUW implementation, although it was supported in older versions.

That `returns null on null input`  clause was present in Db2-LUW versions 7.x, 8.x, 9.1, 9.5, 9.7, 10.1, 10.5, but was removed from the documentation (and presumably removed from the product) from Db2-LUW v11.1 onwards.

Reference Db2-LUW documentation [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-function-sql-scalar-table-row).

Comment: Sry, I missed the NOT FENCED clause that is visible in my error... Anyway, your answer helped me to understand. I found the documentation for function (external scalar) which still has all keywords. [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-function-external-scalar) But for LANGUAGE SQL (default) I have to look at your link (sql scalar).